# Is it possible to initialize a variable with a hidden/extra argument?

Tags: javascript, recursion, methods, arguments

Keeping in mind that I've only been coding for 2 weeks, I can't find anything on how to initialize a variable with a hidden/extra argument placed in a recursive function call. Is it possible? And, if it is possible, is there ever a scenario where doing so is best practices?

---

This question came up as I was fuddling through completing a super inelegant answer to [CoderByte challenge number 10](http://www.coderbyte.com/CodingArea/Challenges/) (Alphabet Soup - take in a string and return a string of the same length that is in alphabetical order). [Note: Yes, I am aware that my answer is dumb and that there are better ways to solve the problem. I don't need help with the problem. I am only including this code as context for my question.]

Essentially, I'm asking if there is a way to remove newStr as an argument (since Java Script functions can take in extra arguments) and still pass through an answer string that is growing recursively? If I simply remove newStr as an argument, newStr is no longer initialized. However, if I initialize newString in the function body (var newStr = "") , I can't continue to pass through my sorted string recursively. If there is a way to do it, is there a use case where this type of approach makes sense? Or, is this just a sign that says, "Do it another way."

Full Code:

```js
function AlphabetSoup(str, newStr) { 
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var testVal= 0;
  //I'M ATTEMPTING TO PASS THROUGH AN ANSWER STRING THAT IS GROWING RECURSIVELY
  if (newStr == null)
    var newStr = "";
  if (str.length == 0)
    return newStr;
  for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (alphabet.indexOf(str[0]) <= alphabet.indexOf(str[i])) {
      testVal += 1;
    }
  }
  // When the first letter, str[0], is ealier in the alphabet than every other letter
  if (testVal == (str.length - 1)) {
    //add the first letter to the newStr
    newStr = newStr + str[0];
    //remove the first letter from the input string
    str = str.substr(1);
    //recursively call AlphabetSoup to continue building newStr
    return AlphabetSoup(str, newStr);
  }
  //When the first letter isn't the earliest in the alphabet
  else {
    //put in in the back of str
    str = str.substr(1) + str[0];
    //until we find the next letter earliest in the alphabet
    return AlphabetSoup(str, newStr);
  }
}

console.log(AlphabetSoup("hooplah"));
```

Comment: `newStr` would be `undefined`, not `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can check `arguments.length` and initialise your variable with `arguments[1]`, if that's what you're referring to by "*JavaScript functions can take in extra arguments*", but that would be rather crude. There's nothing wrong with having that argument there. If you don't want to expose it to your callers, wrap your recursive function in another function that has only a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to check `newStr` at the beginning is a common  pattern in JS. But don't check if it's `null`, but `undefined`:

```
if (typeof newStr == "undefined") {
    var newStr = "";
}
```

If you write ES6 (or Coffeescript), you can have default values for your arguments:

```
function AlphabetSoup(str, newStr = '') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Every argument is optional in JavaScript, since the very beginning. I think what you meant are *default arguments*.